# I wrote a C++ Palindrome without using string.h. It works fine without the Do-While loop. But as i tried make a loop it prints the result many times

Tags: c++, string

```
     #include <iostream>

     #include <conio.h>

    using namespace std; 

    void main()

    {
```

> initializing the variables

```
     int i,j,len;

     char exit[5]={'E','X','I','T','\0'};
     char a[20];
     bool flag;
     flag=true;


    do

    {


    cout<<"Enter a string:";


    cin>>a;
```

> to initialize checking the characters

```
    for(len=0;a[len]!='\0';++len);
```

> to check the input from the start and the end

```
    for(i=0, j=len-1 ; i<len/2;++i,--j) 

      {
       if(a[j]!=a[i])      
       flag=false;
      }
```

> if they are not equal then the condition is false

```
      if(flag!=true)
```

> if they are equal then it is palindrome

```
     cout<<"\nThe string is Palindrome "<<endl;

      else
           cout<<"\nThe string is not Palindrome "<<endl;

    }while(a[i]!=exit[i]);
```

> when the user input is equat to "EXIT" the loop ends

```
     cout<<"\n\nGood Bye and Take Care..!!"<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your post and provide a description of the exact problem, including input, output, what results you were expecting, what results you got, etc. etc. Also please don't break up code like that with comments as regular text every couple few lines.

Comment: you probably meant to compare `a` with the array `exit` (eg. with `strcmp`, or another string comparison loop if you don't want to use `string.h`) instead of just `a[i]` with `exit[i]` (especially since the index `i` could be out-of-bound for array `exit`)

Comment: Next time, just post your code, we can read it without the quotes in between.

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to simplify the function to see the flow better. Your code is similar to this code:

```
char exit[5]={'E','X','I','T','\0'};
char a[20];

do {
    cout<<"Enter a string:";
    cin>>a;
    printIfPalendrome();
} while(a[i]!=exit[i]);
```

Which means that the printIfPalendrome() will always print multiple times, because it will print for each index of a[].  This is because the behavior of the while clause is not what you intended.

Comment: is there any other way...
i tried

}while(a!="EXIT") 

BUT  it didn't work either

Comment: You are using iostream, you should probably be using std::string, which would work the way you intend.   If you aren't using std::string for a specific reason, you need to implement a separate loop to check if the input string is equal to "EXIT".  Don't combine the main loop and the comparison check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want use cstring but any way...
If you want check if some string is equal to another, they should have the sam ASCII range - so EXIT != exit, that is why i use toupper() from cctype. I add some comments, where it's seem to me you have bad code. Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
//for using toupper()
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
//void main() - main must return integer in the end of working
int main()
{
//initializing the variables
 int i,j,len;
 //exit is function from <cstdlib>, so it is better to use some other word
 char stop[5]={'E','X','I','T','\0'};
 char a[20];
 bool flag;
 //additional variable to check if the word is 'exit'
 bool check_exit = true;
do {
//for every new word you have to set flag befor compare
flag = true;
cout<<"Enter a string:";
cin>>a;

for(len=0;a[len]!='\0';++len);
//this is an example how to control end of program without strcmp or cstring library
if(len<5){   //we compare with 5-long array stop[]
    for(i=0;i<len+1;++i){
        if(toupper(a[i])!=stop[i]){
            check_exit = true;
            break;
        } else check_exit = false;  //end program
    }
}
for(i=0, j=len-1 ; i<len/2;++i,--j){

   if(a[j]!=a[i]){
   flag=false;
   break;      //if only one character is wrong the rest is dosen't metter
   }
  }
  //if(flag!=true) - wrong logic
 if(flag)
    cout<<"\nThe string is Palindrome "<<endl;
 else
    cout<<"\nThe string is not Palindrome "<<endl;

}while(check_exit);

 cout<<"\n\nGood Bye and Take Care..!!"<<endl;

 return 0;
```

}